# Name on pay stubs does not match my visa and passport.

Tags: h1-visa, payment

I am working in USA on H1B visa. I have recently joined with a new Employer. The name on pay stubs issued by the new employer has some spelling mistakes and doesn't match the name on my visa and passport. And bad part each month it has different names. I have escalated to my Employer and they say that they will issue new pay checks with correct name. How ever I would like to know.

- Does it causes any issues related VISA and Green Card processing?
- If yes what is the remedy for it?

Comment: Are the spelling mistakes caused by a mistake or a technical inability to write your name correctly (so called romanization)?

Answer (score 6):

Your records, to the extent they are linked at all, are linked through your SSN. When you get paid, your salary information is reported by your employer to the IRS and SSA. Your SSA records are linked to your USCIS records because SSA checks with USCIS before issuing your SSN.

A spelling mistake in your pay records is unlikely to affect USCIS processing. However, it's probably a good idea to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Your Green Card or renewing you H1B won't be affected, even if your employer never fixes it; which they will.

The only people who care about the paychecks are you and the IRS (well, and your state's income tax bureaucracy). There's no important linkage in this case between your money and your immigration status.